# Not able to retrieve data after executing preparatory statement in Eclipse after JDBC Connection

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc

Here is the preparatory statement I am using after making jdbc connection (Using SQL Developer) but on execution I am getting the following error

```
resultsetoracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@762f5aa3
```

I am able to retrieve data from database if not using preparatory statement. Not sure if the problem with the resultset I am using to see the results.

```
System.out.println("resultset" + rs);
```

Please help. Thanks in advance
I am using the following jar (OJDBC6-11.2.0.2.0)

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Connection conn= null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("connecting to a database");
            //Making JDBC connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
            System.out.println("Database connection successfully");
            System.out.println("creating statement");
             String query = "select * from event where externaleventid=?";
              PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 

            //Bind values into the parameters.
              pstmt.setString(1,"1256294"); 
               ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

              System.out.println("resultset" + rs);
              conn.close();


        } catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){

            }
        }try {
            if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();

        }catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }   


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error. What you are printing out is the `toString` of the result set, and not the contents of the result set. Try looping through `rs.next()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like `rs.getString("mycolumn")` to get the result for a column named "mycolumn" which is stringlike data (call appropriate methods for appropriate types) but you do have to loop through the result set using `next()`.  The `next()` method returns a boolean to let you know when you are done.  So:

```
while (rs.next()){
   System.out.println(rs.getString("mycolumn"));
}
```

Both column positions (1,2,3,...) and column names are legitimate ways of addressing the columns

**EDIT**

In case this is helpful, how you find out number of columns in result set:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
```

You can also do like

```
rsmd.getColumnType(1);
rsmd.getColumnLabel(1);
rsmd.getColumnDisplaySize(1);
```

to get further information about the column 1 for example.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  i am using while (rs.next()) {
  
     String externaleventid = rs.getString("externaleventid");
      
     System.out.println("externaleventid : " + externaleventid);}and i am getting only the result of the column. Is there a way when we execute query it will display the whole query result instead of just column. Since i am using * in my query and table has more than 10 column. How can i get the results printed on the console for all the columns.

Comment: You can use StringBuilder and append them all together I suppose.  You probably in this case would want the number option.  This is 1-based.  So if you know 10 columns, you do for loop from 1 to 10.  If you are asking how do I figure out number of columns in my resultset, well read my edit just now.